# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $rootscopeProvider <- $rootscope <- mycontroller

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification

```
ionic.bundle.js:26794 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $rootscopeProvider <- $rootscope <- Pushctlr
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24rootscopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24rootscope%20%3C-%20Pushctlr
    at ionic.bundle.js:13438
    at ionic.bundle.js:17788
    at Object.getService [as get] (ionic.bundle.js:17941)
    at ionic.bundle.js:17793
    at getService (ionic.bundle.js:17941)
    at injectionArgs (ionic.bundle.js:17965)
    at Object.invoke (ionic.bundle.js:17987)
    at $controllerInit (ionic.bundle.js:23397)
    at nodeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:22335)
    at compositeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:21703)
```

I am tring ionic push notification but am struck with this error pls help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake.

Try this: `$rootScope` instead of `$rootscope`